# Resource ids in R.java increase according to alphabetical order of resources - can I rely on it?

Tags: android

I have 26 wav files corresponding to letters of the alphabet in my raw folder. These are "a.wav", "b.wav" ... to "z.wav". When I build the project the SDK assigns ids in R.java like so:

```
public static final class raw {
        public static final int a=0x7f040000;
        public static final int b=0x7f040001;
        public static final int c=0x7f040002;
        public static final int d=0x7f040003;
    .... etc
        public static final int z=0x7f040019;
```

In **practice**, can I rely on Eclipse and Ant builds to assign the values in alphabetical order, increasing by one each time?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on such behavior if you're thinking about using a and z as some sort of limiters you can use to calculate ids in the middle.

Comment: @harism - agreed it looks chancy, but it would save me about 140 switch/case or if statements by the time I'm finished. That's why I ask how it will work in practice. As it stands I can have loops like for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
mTts.addEarcon(Character.toString(c).toUpperCase(), "com.nbt.tts", res_id_a + c - 'a' ); where res_id_a is the base id

Comment: I see. A quick look on a few R classes I had in hand had members sorted by name but their values did not increase accordingly, quite likely for other reasons though. Anyway, is it out of question to introduce a final int array you put all ids ``a`` through ``z``? It left you with pretty much the same possibilities with only somewhat small amount of coding - and it's guaranteed the order is what you expect.

Comment: @harism - yes raw is a final class, as are its int static members but they are generated automatically by the SDK from what it finds in the raw folder. One can only refer to the resource by the id that the compiler gives it like R.raw.a, or in my case by cheating a little by adding the offset to save coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In practice, can I rely on Eclipse and Ant builds to assign the values in alphabetical order, increasing by one each time?

No. There are no documented rules for how they are generated, and so it can change at any point.

> but it would save me about 140 switch/case or if statements by the time I'm finished.

The suggestion by harism is the correct one: maintain your own static array of the IDs.

Comment: In that case would I not have to a line of code that referred to each resource explicitly, e.g idForLetterCWav = r.raw.c in order for me to assemble such an array?

Comment: If you declare ``static final int IDS[] = { R.raw.a, R.raw.b, R.raw.c, ....}`` in your class, you get R.raw.c from IDS[2]. Pretty much the same idea you're after already now with the difference it's zero based indexing.

Comment: @harism - yes of course! Explicit references, but not too much typing! Many thanks to you and to CommonsWare